# How to unzip a buffer to a directory with Nodejs with minimum dependencies?

Tags: node.js, directory, buffer, unzip

I'm receiving a buffer from an API with a Get request. The buffer contains a directory/file structure.

I want to extract the buffer to the file system to a specific base folder.

I'm currently using [unzipper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper), but it fails on Nodejs **v19.8.0** and **v19.8.1** (it was working flawlessly so far).

My current code is:

```
function unzipBufferToFolder(data, folder, callback)
{
    unzip.Open.buffer(data)
        .then(d => d.extract({path: folder}), reportError)
        .then(callback, reportError)
}
```

Unzipper comes with a ton of dependencies, and some of them fail in the newer Nodejs version.
It unzips the files without error messages. However, the unzipped files are broken.

How to unzip a buffer to a directory in Nodejs with minimum dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ADM-ZIP](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip) can extract a ZIP buffer to a folder with **zero** dependencies and **zero** promises.

```
const AdmZip = require('adm-zip')

function unzipBufferToFolder(data, folder)
{
    new AdmZip(data).extractAllTo(folder, /** overwrite **/ true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[yauzl](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl) is pretty minimal but a bit more work.

```
import yauzl from 'yauzl'
import { createWriteStream } from 'node:fs'
import { mkdir } from 'node:fs/promises'
import { promisify } from 'node:util'
import { pipeline } from 'node:stream/promises'
import { join as pathJoin } from 'path'

const yauzlFromBuffer = promisify(yauzl.fromBuffer)

async function unzipBufferToFolder(data, folder){
  const zipfile = await yauzlFromBuffer(data, { lazyEntries: true })
  const openReadStream = promisify(zipfile.openReadStream.bind(zipfile))

  zipfile.on("entry", async function(entry) {
    const file_path = pathJoin(folder, entry.fileName)
    console.log(file_path)
    // Directory
    if (file_path.endsWith('/')) {
      await mkdir(file_path)
      return zipfile.readEntry()
    }
    // File
    await pipeline(
      await openReadStream(entry), 
      createWriteStream(file_path)
    )
    zipfile.readEntry()
  })

  zipfile.readEntry()
  await new Promise((ok) => zipfile.on("end", ok))
  return folder
}
```

Comment: It raises `node:internal/process/promises:289` `Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'c:\folder'`

Comment: Might be the endsWith check on windows? \ instead of `/` ?